# Selecionar informações do dataframe baseado em condições específicas

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Estou trabalhando com dados de eleições para prefeitos no Brasil e gostaria de selecionar na minha base de dados apenas os dados referentes aos municípios baseado em duas condições:

- Municípios onde a disputa se deu apenas entre dois candidatos
  e
- Municípios onde estes dois únicos candidatos eram um homem e uma mulher

Meu data frame segue este tipo:

```
Candidato <- c('Alberto', 'Alessandra', ' Cassio', 'Roberta', 'Denis', 'Flavia', 'Jefferson', 'Henrique', 'Paulo')
Municipio <- c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D')
Genero <- c('M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M')
dados <- data.frame (Candidato, Municipio, Genero)
```

Gostaria de ter um resultado respeitando as condições acima da seguinte forma:

```
Candidato     Municipio     Genero 
Alberto       A               M
Alessandra    A               F
Flavia        C               F
Jefferson     C               M
```

Answer (score 1):

Olha Phill, o código abaixo resolve o seu problema:

```
'%ni%' <- Negate('%in%')
cidades <- unique(dados$Municipio)
for(cidade in cidades)
{
  generos <- subset(dados$Genero, dados$Municipio == cidade)
  if('M' %ni% generos | 'F' %ni% generos | length(generos) > 2)
    dados <- dados[which(dados$Municipio != cidade),]
}
```

O data frame que essa função retornou aqui foi esse:

```
   Candidato Municipio Genero
1    Alberto         A      M
2 Alessandra         A      F
3     Flavia         C      F
4  Jefferson         C      M
```

Comment: Poxa, amigo. O código não funcionou :(  
Simplesmente me retornou o mesmo dataframe.
Agradeço sua contribuição

Comment: Atualizei minha resposta com o data frame que a função retornou. O data frame da pergunta tem 4 municípios diferentes. O meu código exclui os cadidatos da cidade D, que tem ambos os candidatos do sexo masculino. Você pode retestar o código?

Comment: Tinha esquecido de colocar a restrição de ter apenas 2 candidatos, editei a resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Solução `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

dados %>% 
  group_by(Municipio) %>% 
  mutate(var_1 = n()) %>% 
  mutate(var_2 = n_distinct(Genero)) %>% 
  filter(var_1 == 2 & var_2 == 2) %>% 
  select(- c('var_1', 'var_2'))
```

*Output*:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   Municipio [2]
Candidato  Municipio Genero
<fct>      <fct>     <fct> 
1 Alberto    A         M     
2 Alessandra A         F     
3 Flavia     C         F     
4 Jefferson  C         M
```

Onde:

- `group_by(Municipio)` agrupa a variável `Município` em suas categorias (que são 4);
- `mutate(var_1 = n())` especifica o número de contagens de cada categoria de `Município`;
- `mutate(var_2 = n_distinct(Genero))` especifica que quero casos distintos da variável `Genero` (`F` e `M`);
- `filter(var_1 == 2 & var_2 == 2)` filtra de acordo com as condições citadas:

**Municípios onde a disputa se deu apenas entre dois candidatos e**;

**Municípios onde estes dois únicos candidatos eram um homem e uma mulher**